# parsing year from DATE in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

a simple question I'm sure... but i am just drawing a blank on how to get just the ear from a stored DATE in a table. what i am truing to do is generate a query that returns a title, id and the year a course was offered.... and i know i haven't added any thing in the where clause.. here is what i have so far:

```
select title, id,  To_Char(c.START_DATE,'YYYY') AS year
 from (select c.COURSE_TITLE as title, g.STUDENT_ID as id, c.START_DATE
 from COURSES c, COURSE_INFO g) m;
```

i have a start date stored, but i only want the year component

Comment: You need to join your two tables somehow. I'm almost certain that you not want to create a cartesian product between `courses` and `course_info`. Read up on the `JOIN` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the format() method for Date objects to pull apart dates. Using Dirk's datetext, here is how I would go about breaking up a date into its constituent parts:

`datetxt <- c("2010-01-02", "2010-02-03", "2010-09-10")
datetxt <- as.Date(datetxt)
df <- data.frame(date = datetxt,
                 year = as.numeric(format(datetxt, format = "%Y")),
                 month = as.numeric(format(datetxt, format = "%m")),
                 day = as.numeric(format(datetxt, format = "%d")))`

Which gives:

`> df
        date year month day
1 2010-01-02 2010     1   2
2 2010-02-03 2010     2   3
3 2010-09-10 2010     9  10`

Answer (score 0):

There is a Year function in oracle

```
select title, id,  Year(START_DATE) AS year
 from (select c.COURSE_TITLE as title, g.STUDENT_ID as id, c.START_DATE
 from COURSES c, COURSE_INFO g) m;
```